# Mock HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, moq, httpcontext, xunit

I'm currently writing unit test for my project where I'm using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` at a defined time. Unfortunately, I can't make the test work since `HttpContext` is null when I run the test.

I already tried some solution I found on internet like `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("rmllcc"), new string[0]);` but I can't get it work.

I'm using a `Forms Authenticate system`, `xUnit` with `Moq`. I'm not testing a controller but a `Repository` where I'm just logguing each time a user make use of a particular method. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: So you pass a HttpContext as a parameter to the repository?

Comment: @DanielStackenland No, just using it. Calling the repository from my Controller and just log the value of the loggued user and the time.

Comment: Don't mock `HttpContext`. instead create an abstraction of what it is you want and pass that as a service to your repository. there are many questions on SO about what you are asking and you will see that most of them suggest this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to what your tests are telling you: use the fact that this test is hard to write to think about the structure of your code. You have introduced a dependency in your repository layer to the web application. That's not good. You also have two things going on in your repository: data access and logging.

Maybe wrap the current user in an abstraction that will get the user you need, but can be easily stubbed. Or you could wrap the repository in a decorator that does the logging for you.

Sorry this is not a direct answer to the question but, when tests are hard to write, there is usually a deeper underlying reason that you need to address.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you dont use the HttpContext from the repository, Make a own context class or a Interface wrapping the user-property.

Something like this:

```
 public class MyContext
    {
        public MyContext(string username)
        {
            Username = username;
        }

        public string Username { get; private set; }

        public static MyContext CreateFromHttpContext(HttpContext httpContext){
            return new MyContext(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }


 public class MyRep
    {
        private readonly VtContext _context;

        public MyRep(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        ... other repository code...

    }
```

then just create a `MyContext` in your test:

```
var rep = new MyRep(new MyContext("unittest"));
```